# Rust #![no_std]: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup

Tags: rust, rust-no-std

I wanted to start a Rust no_std project, so I simply created a new cargo package and wrote in main.rs the following lines:

```
#![feature(lang_items, start)]
#![no_std]

extern crate libc;

#[start]
fn main(_argc: isize, _argv: *const *const u8) -> isize{

    1
}

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_: &core::panic::PanicInfo) -> !{
    loop{}
}
#[lang = "eh_personality"] extern fn eh_personality() {}
```

The Cargo.toml file looks like that:

```
[dependencies]
libc = "0.2.71"

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
```

I ran `cargo build` and the linker printed:

```
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
```

What could be the reason behind that error ?

Answer (score 0):

Default build target on windows uses mscv toolchain, which includes a dynamically-linked libc. This ones is a C-runtime, which, in particularly, includes an undefined `main` symbol (which assumed to be defined by a programmer), therefore at linking stage the linker cannot find this missing symbol. You need explicitly specify that you don't need it via `#![no_main]` at the beginning of *main.rs*.

I also would suggest you reading [A Freestanding Rust Binary](https://os.phil-opp.com/freestanding-rust-binary/) which explain much more in details.